# Tem como calcular a diagonal no Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, imagem, canvas

Preciso desenhar um quadrado com o Canvas em uma imagem. Essa imagem vem do banco de dados, onde tem diferenciadas dimensões. Estou conseguindo desenhar o quadrado no centro da imagem, mas se a imagem for com uma largura maior, o Canvas sai da sua proporção. Tem como ao invés de pegar a altura e a largura da imagem, pegar sua diagonal ou polegadas para que o quadrado não saia da proporção?

Aqui está o código utilizado para fazer o Canvas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(i) {
        var img = document.getElementById("foto" + i);
        var cs = getComputedStyle(img);
        var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'));
        var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'));
        $('#contentCanvas' + i).html('<canvas id="myCanvas' + i + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" >');
        drawImg(img, cs, width, height, i);
    }
    function drawImg(img, cs, width, height, i) {
        var myCanvas = 'myCanvas' + i;
        var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
        var c = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        drawRetangle(context, width, height);
    }
    function drawRetangle(context, width, height) {
        position_x = parseInt(width) / 2;
        position_y = parseInt(height) / 2;

        position_x = parseInt(position_x) - 20;
        position_y = parseInt(position_y) - 17;

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(position_x, position_y, 39, 34);
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = '#00FF00';
        context.stroke();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tem sim.

Fórmula da Hipotenusa.

`Hˆ2 = Cˆ2 + Cˆ2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem a altura e a largura, pode calcular a diagonal a partir disto.

Pode ser resolvido utilizando o Teorema de Pitágoras, da seguinte forma:
Diagonal² = altura² + largura²;

Em js:

```
var diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(width,2), 2);
```

Espero ter ajudado.